# Expand input field on focus

Tags: html, css

I want to expand a search box **to the left** on focus. Following code will expand, but it will expand towards right. Is there anyway to expand it to the left?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search">
```

**CSS:**

```
 input[type="text"] {
    background: #444;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #d7d7d7;
    width:50px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
     margin:3px 12px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
    background:#ccc;
    color: #6a6f75;
    width: 120px;    
    margin:3px 12px;
    outline: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/7ppaS/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using `padding-left` to make it expand to the left, along with changing `margin-left` so that the input box stays in the same place:

```
input[type="text"] {
    background: #444;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #d7d7d7;
    width:50px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
     margin:3px 80px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
    background:#ccc;
    color: #6a6f75;
    padding-left:80px;  
    margin-left:35px;
    outline: none;
}
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/7ppaS/4/

Comment: This padding solution is only for decoration purposes. When a long text is typed into the input, the padding prevents full use of the apparent width. Using the width property is still the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

use Direction:rtl in your code:

```
 input[type="text"] {
    background: #444;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #d7d7d7;
    width:50px;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
     margin:3px 12px;
    direction:rtl
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ppaS/8/

Comment: Nice! That one was new for me to!

Comment: that used for right to left Language like persian or arabic,but work anyway

Answer (score 2):

Using `padding` will just create a false width that doesn't allow long text to be displayed within the apparent width. Use the `width` property instead as that is what it was intended for:

```css
input {
  width: 10rem;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
  direction: rtl
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 15rem;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="search">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `padding-left:70px;` on focus. That will expand it to the left.